# Deep merge data from multiple layers

Tags: attribute-joins

Let me explain what I mean by "Deep Merge" and what I am trying to do.

Suppose that I have 3 layers (`Layer1`, `Layer2` and `Layer3)` with the same field names (`field_a`, `field_b` and `field_c`). For any record, each layer has a value only in one of the fields. For example, one row in `Layer1` has a non-empty value only in `field_a`. One row in `Layer2` only in `field_b`. One row in `Layer3` only in `field_c`. The tricky part is that, different rows in the same layer may not have a non-empty value in the same field. My goal is to merge all 3 layers into one target layer, which contains all non-empty values from all 3 layers.

In my mind, it involves some serious loops or joins. So I am wondering if anybody knows any existing tool (open source or commercial) to do that.

Comment: Are you using "row" as a synonym for "feature"?  If not, it's unclear how "rows" in one layer are supposed to be associated with rows in another layer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that Layer1 only has values in field_a, Layer2 only in field_b, and Layer3 only in field_c? Because if so, and assuming they have a shared id, you could try something like this (in a DBMS like PostgreSQL/PostGIS, for example):

```
SELECT Layer1.id AS orig_id, field_a, field_b INTO intermediate_table
FROM Layer1, Layer2 WHERE Layer1.id = Layer2.id;

SELECT orig_id, field_a, field_b, Layer3.field_c AS field_c INTO merged_table 
FROM intermediate_table, Layer3 WHERE intermediate_table.orig_id = Layer3.id;
```

However, I suspect you mean that the combination of Layers 1, 2 and 3 always populates field_a, field_b and field_c when combined, but different rows from the same table would not always have a non-null value for the same field? Then yes, it could get a whole lot more complicated...

**EDIT:**

OK, so given that there is no id field, and that the non-null field is not the same one between rows in the same table, try something like this instead. First, create the target table for the merge:

```
SELECT * FROM Layer1 INTO merged;
UPDATE merged SET field_a = null;
UPDATE merged SET field_b = null;
UPDATE merged SET field_c = null;
```

Then, for every field in every Layer you want to merge, do this:

```
UPDATE merged SET field_X =
  (SELECT LayerY.field_X FROM LayerY
  WHERE LayerY.the_geom = merged.the_geom AND LayerY.field_X IS NOT NULL);
```

I'm assuming here that the geometries are in fact identical (as in, derived from the same table originally), and are called "the_geom". If they are not identical, you'll have to modify the WHERE clause to use some SQL functions from PostGIS which can detect spatial intersection/overlap/etc.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't have a shared ID. Also different rows from the same table may not always have a non-null value for the same field.The only common denominator is the similar shapes.

Comment: OK, my idea is too long to put in a comment, so I'll edit my answer instead.

Comment: Thanks R! That looks like a pretty promising solution, although the geometries are not identical, I could work further on your idea. And my database is Oracle (without spatial). I will see if I could apply SDE geometries on the same idea.

Comment: No probs! :) The general idea should work though, as long as there's some way to uniquely identify each row between the different tables.